# Why does Node.js exit without an Exception after 2 - 5 minutes

Tags: node.js, socket.io, node-serialport

EDIT-- Node is running in a Windows 8.1 environment.
I am using the serialport module and socket.io to read data from an Arduino.  I am getting data beautifully for 2 - 5 min.  Then node stops running, no exception is thrown, and I'm left clueless.  I've tried with just 'http' module, and with 'express'.  Same results either way.  Full source code below.

---

server.js

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var server = app.listen(3000, function () {

var host = server.address().address
var port = server.address().port

console.log('Example app listening at http://%s:%s', host, port)

});
var io = require('socket.io').listen(server);
var serialport = require('serialport');
var SerialPort = serialport.SerialPort;
var serialPort = new SerialPort("COM3",{
baudrate:9600,
dataBits: 8,
parity: 'none',
flowControl: false,
parser: serialport.parsers.readline("<EOD>")
});


app.use(express.static(__dirname));

app.get('/', function (req, res) {
res.render('./index.html')
});

serialPort.on('open', function(){
// Now server is connected to Arduino
console.log('Serial Port Opened');

 var lastValue;
io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {
  //Connecting to client 
  console.log('Socket connected');
  //socket.emit('connected');
  var lastValue;

      serialPort.on('data', function(data){
      //if(lastValue !== data.toString()){
          socket.emit('data', data.toString());
          console.log(data.toString());
      //}
      lastValue = data.toString();
    });
  });
});
```

index.html script: contains all socket.io functionality.

```
<script>

    function handleIO(){

        function serverDisconnect(){
            console.log("Server Disconnected.");
            console.log(new Date().toTimeString());
        }
        socket.timeout = 60*60*1000;

        socket.on('disconnect', serverDisconnect);

        socket.on('data', function(data) {
            //console.log("Got Data");
            console.log(data);
            render(data);   
        });

        console.log("Connected To Server.");
        console.log(new Date().toTimeString());
    }

    var socket = io();

    socket.on('connect', handleIO);


</script>
```

EDIT #2: Console log:

```
C:\Users\Dave\Desktop\js\js\Websensors2>node serverexp.js
Example app listening at http://:::3000
Port open
New Socket Client connected: JPozMKfwH77x8uMNAAAA
Sent data to connected Socket clients
74.59
Sent data to connected Socket clients
74.70
Sent data to connected Socket clients
74.73
Sent data to connected Socket clients
74.62
Sent data to connected Socket clients
74.80
Sent data to connected Socket clients
74.77
Sent data to connected Socket clients
74.73
Sent data to connected Socket clients
74.73
Sent data to connected Socket clients
74.73
Sent data to connected Socket clients
74.73
Sent data to connected Socket clients
74.73
Sent data to connected Socket clients
74.70
Sent data to connected Socket clients
74.73
Sent data to connected Socket clients
74.70
Sent data to connected Socket clients
74.70
Sent data to connected Socket clients
74.73
Sent data to connected Socket clients
74.73
Sent data to connected Socket clients
74.77
Sent data to connected Socket clients
74.73
Sent data to connected Socket clients
74.73
Sent data to connected Socket clients
74.73
Sent data to connected Socket clients
74.73
Sent data to connected Socket clients
74.73
Sent data to connected Socket clients
74.73
Sent data to connected Socket clients
74.70
Sent data to connected Socket clients
74.73
Sent data to connected Socket clients
74.66
Sent data to connected Socket clients
74.66
Sent data to connected Socket clients
74.66
Sent data to connected Socket clients
74.66
Sent data to connected Socket clients
74.62
Sent data to connected Socket clients
74.62
Sent data to connected Socket clients
74.73
Sent data to connected Socket clients
74.70
Sent data to connected Socket clients
74.62
Sent data to connected Socket clients
74.59
Sent data to connected Socket clients
74.66
Sent data to connected Socket clients
74.66
Sent data to connected Socket clients
74.66
Sent data to connected Socket clients
74.62
Sent data to connected Socket clients
74.73
Sent data to connected Socket clients
74.70
Sent data to connected Socket clients
74.66
Sent data to connected Socket clients
74.70
Sent data to connected Socket clients
74.66
Sent data to connected Socket clients
74.70
Sent data to connected Socket clients
74.70
Sent data to connected Socket clients
74.62
Sent data to connected Socket clients
74.66
Sent data to connected Socket clients
74.55
Sent data to connected Socket clients
74.52
Sent data to connected Socket clients
74.55
Sent data to connected Socket clients
74.55
Sent data to connected Socket clients
74.55
Sent data to connected Socket clients
74.55
Sent data to connected Socket clients
74.44
Sent data to connected Socket clients
74.44
Sent data to connected Socket clients
74.41
Sent data to connected Socket clients
74.44
Sent data to connected Socket clients
74.55
Sent data to connected Socket clients
74.55
Sent data to connected Socket clients
74.55
Sent data to connected Socket clients
74.55
Sent data to connected Socket clients
74.48
Sent data to connected Socket clients
74.52
Sent data to connected Socket clients
74.55
Sent data to connected Socket clients
74.55
Sent data to connected Socket clients
74.59
Sent data to connected Socket clients
74.55
Sent data to connected Socket clients
74.41
Sent data to connected Socket clients
74.44
Sent data to connected Socket clients
74.44
Sent data to connected Socket clients
74.44
Sent data to connected Socket clients
74.55
Sent data to connected Socket clients
74.52
Sent data to connected Socket clients
74.55
Sent data to connected Socket clients
74.55
Sent data to connected Socket clients
74.48
Sent data to connected Socket clients
74.44
Sent data to connected Socket clients
74.44
Sent data to connected Socket clients
74.52
Sent data to connected Socket clients
74.48
Sent data to connected Socket clients
74.55
Sent data to connected Socket clients
74.52
Sent data to connected Socket clients
74.48
Sent data to connected Socket clients
74.55
Sent data to connected Socket clients
74.52
Sent data to connected Socket clients
74.55
Sent data to connected Socket clients
74.44
Sent data to connected Socket clients
74.52
Sent data to connected Socket clients
74.55
Sent data to connected Socket clients
74.52
Sent data to connected Socket clients
74.55
Sent data to connected Socket clients
74.55
Sent data to connected Socket clients
74.52
Sent data to connected Socket clients
74.55
Sent data to connected Socket clients
74.55
Sent data to connected Socket clients
74.55
Sent data to connected Socket clients
74.55
Sent data to connected Socket clients
74.55
Sent data to connected Socket clients
74.52
Sent data to connected Socket clients
74.52
Sent data to connected Socket clients
74.55
Sent data to connected Socket clients
74.44
Sent data to connected Socket clients
74.44
Sent data to connected Socket clients
74.48
Sent data to connected Socket clients
74.48
Sent data to connected Socket clients
74.44
Sent data to connected Socket clients
74.52
Sent data to connected Socket clients
74.55
Sent data to connected Socket clients
74.55
Sent data to connected Socket clients
74.52
Sent data to connected Socket clients
74.55
Sent data to connected Socket clients
74.59
Sent data to connected Socket clients
74.55
Sent data to connected Socket clients
74.62
Sent data to connected Socket clients
74.55
Sent data to connected Socket clients
74.48
Sent data to connected Socket clients
74.55
Sent data to connected Socket clients
74.55
Sent data to connected Socket clients
74.59
Sent data to connected Socket clients
74.59
Sent data to connected Socket clients
74.55
Sent data to connected Socket clients
74.55
Sent data to connected Socket clients
74.55
Sent data to connected Socket clients
74.55
Sent data to connected Socket clients
74.59
Sent data to connected Socket clients
74.59
Sent data to connected Socket clients
74.59
Sent data to connected Socket clients
74.55
Sent data to connected Socket clients
74.59
Sent data to connected Socket clients
74.59
Sent data to connected Socket clients
74.55
Sent data to connected Socket clients
74.55
Sent data to connected Socket clients
74.55
Sent data to connected Socket clients
74.55
Sent data to connected Socket clients
74.52
Sent data to connected Socket clients
74.48
Sent data to connected Socket clients
74.52
Sent data to connected Socket clients
74.55
Sent data to connected Socket clients
74.52
Sent data to connected Socket clients
74.52
Sent data to connected Socket clients
74.44
Sent data to connected Socket clients
74.48
Sent data to connected Socket clients
74.52
Sent data to connected Socket clients
74.55
Sent data to connected Socket clients
74.55
Sent data to connected Socket clients
74.55
Sent data to connected Socket clients
74.55
Sent data to connected Socket clients
74.55
Sent data to connected Socket clients
74.55
Sent data to connected Socket clients
74.59
Sent data to connected Socket clients
74.55

C:\Users\Dave\Desktop\js\js\Websensors2>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think had the same problem you. I solved when serialport released new version 3 days ago (2.0.4).

My issue on serialport github: https://github.com/voodootikigod/node-serialport/issues/609

Try reinstall serialport module using npm now, fully compatible with node 4.2.2 LTS :)

Answer (score 0):

It appears this is related to a least one known issue with the serialport library.  It appears the best short-term fix is to rollback to a prior release of serialport.  The issue is documented on github. Thanks for your help. Wish I had found that before posting.

Answer (score -1):

I have made some changes to your source code 'server.js', Please use the modified source code provided below. I have included separate events to log different events for both Socket.IO and Serial Port.

http: runs in port 3000
socket.io: runs in port as http
serialPort: connected to server through serial port

1. Open http connection
2. Open serialPort
3. Open Socket.IO
4. Receive data from serial port
5. Forward received data from serial port to Socket IO clients

   `server.js`

   ```
   var express = require('express');
   var app = express();

   var SerialPort = require('serialport');
   var http = require('http').Server(app);
   var io = require('socket.io')(http);

   var options_serialPort = {
       baudrate: 9600,
       dataBits: 8,
       parity: 'none',
       flowControl: false,
       parser: serialport.parsers.readline("<EOD>")
   };

   var serialPort = new SerialPort("COM3", options_serialPort);

   app.use(express.static(__dirname));

   app.get('/', function (req, res) {
       res.render('./index.html')
   });

   serialPort.on('open', function () {
       // Callback called when serial port is opened
       console.log('Port open');
   });

   serialPort.on('data', function (data) {
       // Callback called when serial port is receiving data from Arduino
       sendReceivedDataToSocketIOClients(data);
       console.log(data.toString());
   });

   serialPort.on('close', function (error) {
       // Callback called when serial port is closed
       console.log('Port closed');
   });

   serialPort.on('error', function (error) {
       // Callback called when serial port receives any error
       console.log('Error in Port: ' + error);
   });

   function sendReceivedDataToSocketIOClients(data) {

       // sending to all socket clients
       io.emit('data', data.toString());
       console.log('Sent data to connected Socket clients');

       //console.log('No Socket clients connected to send data');
   }

   io.on('connection', function (socket) {
       console.log("New Socket Client connected: " + socket.id);

       socket.on("connect", function () {
           console.log("Socket Client Connected!");
       });

       socket.on('disconnect', function () {
           console.log("Socket Client Disconnected!");
       });

   });

   http.listen(3000, function () {
       var host = server.address().address;
       var port = server.address().port;

       console.log('Example app listening at http://%s:%s', host, port);
   });
   ```

Comment: Ran the new source code, and same issue.  It exits without throwing any exceptions after 3 minutes....

Comment: @DavidPolly Please provide the console log to proceed and investigate further

Comment: Console log added to original post.